# How do I maintain a consistent db for a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations

Edit for clarity: 
I have edited a record in a table in the db. I would like for this record to be consistent across all users who are using the project. All of us are using the same copy of a scrubbed db. 
I know I could create a migration file for this change but I've seen that migrations are usually used for schema changes of the db.
I'm new to rails so please do bear with me.

Comment: The question is missing the clarity whether you are checking with Migration or syntax or rails specific details. Please add more context

Comment: To be honest with you, I didn't understand what you're trying to ask and your problem here is. Can you please elaborate a little more ?

Comment: My question basically is, can i use migration for updating records in a table? in other words to sync the record across the users.

Comment: For changing database that does not relate to schema changes, you can write a rake task, then ask the team to run that rake task. Ex: you want to change all `user_uid` from a plain string into a string like `<provider_name>-user_uid_string`

Comment: @Techguy1611 _"can i use migration for updating records in a table?"_ – yes, you can. From [Migrations and Seed Data](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data): _"Migrations can also be used to add or modify data."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  you can use rails migration for updating database values.  Here is a sample of adding new column and updating values for every user:

```
class AddStatusToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :users, :status, :string
    User.find_each do |user|
      user.status = 'active'
      user.save!
    end
  end

  def down
    remove_column :users, :status
  end
end
```

In your case you can create new migration and put code to update any table any column value.